# Use more than one ID in Google Analytics for iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, google-analytics

```
[[GANTracker sharedTracker] startTrackerWithAccountID:@"UA-0000000-1"
                                        dispatchPeriod:kGANDispatchPeriodSec
                                              delegate:nil];
```

Can I make my app use more that one ID and send items to different IDs?